# Select in C, why does it fail?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, file-descriptor

I'm reviewing a code in C with [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) function. In this code, select function should return a number different from 0 when any of a set of two sockets it's ready. However it fails to find any file descriptor ready even though the sockets are declared just before the select and when I *netstat --listen* I get that one of the sockets (cmd_socket) is listening on its specified port. I've tried forcing different timeouts and I assume FD_SETSIZE is ok because this code used to work in another machine. What do is wrong?
This is the code:

```
 // Program sockets intialization
int cmd_sock = create_and_bind_socket(cmd_port_property(0,GET) ,&src_addr);
mc_sock = create_and_bind_socket(mcast_port_property(0,GET), &mc_addr); 
join_multicast_group(mc_sock,mc_addr_str, &mc_req);


int recv_len = 0;
int childs = 0;

struct timeval tv;
struct timeval *ptv = &tv;

if (!timeout) {

  ptv = NULL;

} else {

  ptv->tv_sec = timeout;
  ptv->tv_usec = 0;

}

fd_set readfds, safe;
fdmax = mc_sock;

// Add multicast and unicast sockets to set
FD_ZERO(&readfds);
FD_SET(cmd_sock, &readfds);
FD_SET(mc_sock, &readfds);

safe = readfds;

// Wait until some socket on the set is ready to be read 
while(select (FD_SETSIZE,&readfds,NULL,NULL,ptv))  {
```

Comment: What do you mean "fails"? Returns zero, or `-1`? Are you calling it with a timeout?

Comment: It's a little odd to set the first argument to FD_SETSIZE rather than fdmax, but that won't be your problem. What makes you think the sockets are ready, and which one is it you think should be readable?

Comment: Select returns 0. 
I'm quite a newbie in file descriptors and sets However, since in another machine the same code works and when I nestat --listen cmd_socket is listening I assume it's ready but I can be wrong.

Comment: PD I've edited my question because the socket that is listening is cmd_socket and not mc_socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the first argument to [`select(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) is **`the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1`**, not the `FD_SETSIZE`, which is just the number of bytes an `fd_set` takes.

Then zero return from `select(2)` means timeout expired. Check if you really have data on the wire, use [`tcpdump(1)`](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) or [`wireshark`](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it's still not clear to me. I've updated select's first argument to max(mc_sock, cmd_sock) and it still doesn't work.
In the other hand, I have tried timeout NULL (in order to wait forever) and it doesn't work either. When I sniff it with Wireshark there is data for cmd_socket but it can not obviously read it since the receive is inside the while.

Comment: @user *Just because it's listening doesn't mean it heard anything.* It'll only be marked readable when a client turns up. Until then, it just sits quietly listening, waiting.

Comment: @NicholasWilson Thank you for your comment. Excuse me for my ignorance but, if the socket is not readable until a client turns up what do I should do to make the socket marked readable? Wouldn't be the code I've posted a client to make it readable?

Comment: No, listening TCP socket becomes readable when client initiates a TCP connection with `connect(2)`. UDP socket becomes readable when the OS receives a datagram sent to its bound port.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov Then my socket should be readable since it's an UDP socket and I see a datagram headed to its port and adress in wireshark comming from another program in my machine. I am right?

Comment: Well, your loop ends on the first timeout. Does data arrive before that? Ports/IPs are correct? And fix that first argument to `select(2)`.

Comment: @Nikolai It's a bit inefficient, but he's FD_ZERO'ing the whole set, so passing FD_SETSIZE should be perfectly OK (I don't think there's an off-by-one...) Idiosyncratic at best though.

Comment: also, `max(mc_sock, cmd_sock)` is not enough, you need `+ 1`